# Multiple Yammer feeds on same sharepoint page

Tags: 2013, integration, yammer

as part of a new intranet I am making for the company I am looking into Yammer and how it works with onsite SharePoint.

Using yammer basic I have set up a couple of groups and have run into a slight problem with trying to put them into the same page in SharePoint using js.

**Problem:**
Using Content Editor or Script editor it simply adds the next feed underneath the previous feed. All functionality is maintained however I would like to have the ability to place feeds in different areas on a page.

At the moment I am aiming for a page to contain: yammer myfeed, sharepoint feed, yammer group feed which I intended to show management the difference between the various feeds.

**Edit**
For the record I have no problem in showing the feeds in SharePoint. The problem is that instead of being in seperate areas of the same page they get attached to each other and display in the same column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, but finally figured it out.

I've used the Script Editor Web Part twice on the same page, with virtually the same script, but with one small change...

```
   <div id="embedded-feed"
```

needs changing for each instance of the group feeds. My first one used the default as above, but the second one I called

```
   <div id="embedded-feed1"
```

which needs referencing in the 'container' section later on.

I guess if you keep it the same, it'll put every group feed into the same container, that's what the problem was.

So the full scripts for both parts are as follows:

First one:

```
    <div id="embedded-feed" style="height:500px;width:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets.yammer.com/.../script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "my network name, change to yours here",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "all",
    config: {header: false}
    });
    </script>
```

Second one:

```
    <div id="embedded-feed1" style="height:500px;width:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets.yammer.com/.../script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed1",
    network: "my network name, change to yours here",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "my group ID number, change to yours here",
    config: {header: false}
    });
    </script>
```

(note: I've chosen to remove the header on mine - delete the 'config' entry if you want to keep it)

cheers
James.

Comment: Well I feel kind of stupid for not thinking of that.

Comment: It took me two days of getting nowhere searching to figure it out, these things are sent to try us!

Comment: great post - thank you for this - I appreciate it!